# publish yii2 project and prevent access to source code

Tags: yii, yii2, publish

I design a project with yii2 framwork for my Customer .
I upload it on hosting ،now i want prevent of access Customer  to my code that design
Now everone access to my code in hosting ، can copy my code and use other hosting
For this i want prevent access every one in my code project
That get me project instat of copy this form hosting
This question is summary:
Convert yii project to .exe software and install in hosting and prevent access Base my code

Comment: Title makes sense, question body makes zero.

Comment: i want just:prevent that: my customer  copy my code project and use another hosting with out let me.  summary: i want lock my code :|

Comment: You're looking for software that does _code obfuscation_.